# In jQuery UI, why doesn't .ui-state-default apply to .ui-icon?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been trying to theme jQuery UI with Theme Roller. I think I have found a bug. If you change the *Icon* colour for *Clickable: default state* then it is not applying to the accordion icons or to the framework icons. Is this a bug in jQuery UI or a bug in ThemeRoller?

1. Set Icon colour to Black (**#000000**) in *Clickable: Default State*

[image: Set Icon colour to Black (#000000) in Clickable: Default State]

2. Icon in Accordion is not black

[image: Icon in Accordion is not black]

3. Icon in Framework Icons is not black

[image: Icon in Framework Icons is not black]

4. In the DOM you can see that the `<span class="ui-icon">` has a parent div with class `ui-state-default` however it is not styled with the correct colour specified in theme roller

[image: In the DOM you can see that the <span class="ui-icon"> has a parent div with class ui-state-default however it is not styled with the correct colour specified in theme roller]

Comment: You should file this bug on the JQuery UI site instead of SO.

Comment: @beerwin I agree but the first rule of jQuery bug reporting is "Make sure it's a bug". See: http://contribute.jquery.org/bug-reports/  I was hoping the community could confirm if it's a bug or if I'm missing something as well as identify if the bug is in jQuery UI or just in the Themeroller application. The community may also be able to provide a workaround that might benefit other users...